# What is the adjacency matrix for k-regular graphs, and for bipartite graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

What is the adjacency matrix for $k-$regular graphs, and for bipartite graphs?

I suppose that the general form for the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph is:
\begin{equation*}
A_{K_{n,\: m}}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\
B^T & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $B$ is $n \times m$ matrix in which $|V1| = n$ and $|V2| = m$.

The general form for the adjacency matrix of a regular $k-$graphs, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have a general form, but they always have $k$ as an eigenvalue if that helps. (Because the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is an eigenvector ).

I guess you could say the general form is that each row has $k$ ones.

Comment: And each column.

Comment: well yeah they are the $01$ symmetric matrices with trace equal to $0$ and every row sum equal to $1$.